# Surface area of a tetrahedron

Tags: geometry

The base ABC of a tetrahedron ABCP is a right triangle with
$∠ABC = π/2$. The edge $P A = 4$ is the altitude of the tetrahedron. Given that
$AB = BC = 3$, find the surface area of the tetrahedron

SA= $(4)(3\sqrt2)/2 + (4)(3)/2+(3)(3)/2+(\sqrt{91}/4)(3)/2$

Comment: any thoughts by yourself?

Comment: The faces are three right triangles and an isosceles triangle. You know the edges lengths, hence what is difficult in computing the area of each face?

Comment: I found the lateral areas of each triangle and the area of the base triangle.  Ill post my results, although I feel like they are not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we look at a tetrahedron, there is one important observation to make: It is made up of 4 triangles. Having 4 triangles, lets work on them individually:

$\triangle ABC:$ We know $\angle ABC=\pi/2$ and $AB=BC=3$ (and $AC=3\sqrt2$), so for a triangle we know that the area $a$ is equal to $\frac12 hb$ with $h$ the height and $b$ the base, so in this case we have $a_{\triangle ABC}=\frac12\cdot3\cdot3$.

$\triangle ABP:$ Using the same method as before we know $a_{\triangle ABP}=\frac12\cdot4\cdot3=6$.

$\triangle BCP:$ $a_{\triangle BCP}=\frac12 BC\cdot AP=2\cdot3=6$.

$\triangle ACP:$ $a_{\triangle ACP}=\frac12 AC\cdot AP=6\sqrt2$.

Thus, the total area (sum of all 4 triangles) is: $12+\frac92+6\sqrt2$

Note that the only reason you needed the angle was to calculate $AC$.

Comment: Thank you.  I guess I misunderstood the notion of PA being the altitude. I did not use it in the calculation of area of ABP.

Comment: I agree that the notation was confusing. Usually one wouldn't consider that the height of the tetraherdron. In this case however, you could realise that this was the case by noting how it was defined as the line segment $PA$.